# Sharing code across mobile plataforms

Tags: java, android, blackberry, symbian, mobile-phones

Is it possible to share a Java application across several mobile platforms (Android, BlackBerry, Symbian, etc) regarding of Android is a Java SE (almost compliant), BlackBerry is JavaME, etc?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

I'm not talking about GUI which it won't be possible.

There is another things which do I have to take care ?, i.e Vector instead of List.

Threads?

Memory management?

Storage management?

Items referred above is where my interest particularly is focused on.

Thanks all for your answers.

Comment: Colin's answer is pretty good, so I'll just add ... it might be possible for you to package some common J2ME code as a Jar and share that. It's what we do with our Android, BlackBerry and plain J2ME apps.

Answer (score 5):

You can keep your code as long as it's compatible with JME (more or less Java SE 1.3) and it only uses libraries compatible.

You can't really keep your GUI and almost everything will have to be recoded.

To sum up, you can keep most of your domain objects as long as it doesn't uses syntax from last Java versions, but the rest will have to be rewritten.

The best thing to do is to rewrite everything IMO.

Comment: I agree. I'm sure that there will be some classes that you write that will be platform independent, but because the paradigms of Android and Blackberry, ext are so different, you may end up redesigning everything anyways.